# How to group Http requests with transactions in Jmeter HTML Reports?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-maven-plugin

HTML Reports generated with JMeter don't show requests grouped under a particular transaction. All requests and transactions appear in the HTML report Randomly. Is there a way to arranage those requests as part of transactions in the HTML Reports.
Is there any plugin which can do that, if this feature is not native to JMeter ?

Any pointers will be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give naming convention for requests as shown below:-

[image]

First, Script Name "SC01" then transaction sequence "00" "and then name for the request or action name. i.e.SC01_00_Homepage.

I hope this help.

For auto increment, initialize a variable let say "id" with 0 in the user defined variable then use ${__intSum(${id},1,id)} for auto increment as shown below:-

[image]
[image]

For reset, use jSR223 post processor in the last sampler to reset the id to 0 as shown below.

[image]

Below is the snapshot to verify this.
[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a way to autogenerate the middle sequence of 00,01,02 for sorting purpose. I don't want to hard code that number. In future I may have to reinsert a new request between 02 and 03 and therefore the whole sequence will have to be changed manually.. Any automated way of generation of the middle sequence would be helpful? Would you have any inputs on that?

Comment: @Andersonneo..Updated my answer for auto increment. Please check if it helps.

Comment: It works out good if you have only 1 iteration. For the second iteration onwards, it increments the all the indexes again.. like imagine you had three transactions 00,01,02 they becomes 03,04,05 in second iteration.. This should not happen.. This number once given shouldn't increment in every iteration. Some reset should happen but don't know how and where to do it

Comment: @Andersonneo..Updated my answer for reset.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sunny_teo, It worked! I have one question on dynamically controlling thread count in Jmeter. Many people are saying its not possible in JMeter, If you know then I will add a question and you can answer it.. Thanks once again!

Comment: If you want to pass different thread number then you can using property() function>>${__P(group1.threads)} -While running the jmeter via cmd line, you can pass the value of thread using the property function. Check https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P.  Post a question if it is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to change the thread count at Run Time using a beanshell or JSR223, I tried it, I found people saying said that Thread Group can't take an update at runtime

Comment: I think it is not possible or rather, i am not aware of. But, something like this can be achieve by creating a performance plan using "jp@gc - Ultimate Thread Group". There, you can control ramp up and ramp down along with threads and delay. Check if that solves the purpose.